# How to obtain the total number of photos in one area using the panoramio data API?

Tags: panoramio

I am trying to get the total number of photos from one specific area using the panoramio data API.

The following code

```
www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php?set=full&from=0&to=0&minx=-180&miny=-90&maxx=180&maxy=90&mapfilter=false
```

returns

```
{"count":72543250,"has_more":true,"map_location":{"lat":-46.647137999999998,"lon":-72.607527000000005,"panoramio_zoom":0},"photos":[]}
```

count should be around 100 000 000 (the total number of photos in panoramio) and not 72 543 250 and I guess the value of "has_more" should be false.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the total number of photos according to the API and the actual total number of photos in Panoramio is that the API only returns geo-referenced photos and not all photos in Panoramio are geo-referenced.

Answer (score 0):

The 100,000,000 are recent ID, because some ID are deleted, so REAL number may be lower.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean?  Are you trying to say that the output the OP is getting is correct?